# C++ invalid array<T, N> subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, struct

I have made a basic class / struct collection in C++, which has the class `Book`, which I did not include, and some others, aswell as the `struct` **`FixedSizeBookCollection`**. However, when use the `FSCB`, it doesn't work as planned:

*books.h*

```
template<size_t Size> struct FixedSizeBookCollection : private std::array<const Book*, Size>{
    FixedSizeBookCollection(const char* Name) : name_(Name){}
    void operator+=(const Book& Book)try{
        if((*this).size() > Size){
            std::ostringstream errorMessage;
            errorMessage << "The FixedSizeBookCollection " << name_ << "'s size capacity has been overfilled" << std::endl;
            throw std::exception(errorMessage.str().c_str());
        }
        /* Line 97 - */ (*this).at(currentPos++) = &Book;
    }catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::ostringstream errorMessage;
        errorMessage << e.what() << " - on line (approx.) " << (__LINE__ -3);
        throw std::exception(errorMessage.str().c_str());
    }
private:
    const char* name_;
    int currentPos;
};
```

And in *main.cpp*

```
FixedSizeBookCollection<5> Collection("My Fixed Size Collection");
Collection += MyBook;
```

But I get the error:

`Error: invalid array <T, N> subscript on line (approx.) 97`

What is the problem?

Comment: You must tell us where is "line 97"

Comment: clang compiles just fine, except for the exception throwing, I have to change throwing of `std::exception`, which is a base class, to throwing of concrete exception classes, like, std::runtime_error, or any you may chose: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception

Comment: notice that I said _compiles_. Since `.at` do bounds checking, you should also check of initialization as ForEver answered. I just can't say whether you're talking about a compilation error or runtime error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `currentPos` is not initialized. It can have any value. Add to your c-tor initializing of this variable by 0.